# Flutter I am not able to save(image) the file in ios 13

Tags: flutter, ios13

I am using flutter image_picker_saver plugin in one of flutter application. Its working fine in below iOS 13. In iOS 13 it's giving an error.Please advise

code:

```
 final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    var filePath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: pngBytes);
    print(filePath);
```

> Flutter Version: Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 2d2a1ffec9
> (3 weeks ago) • 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700 Engine • revision b863200c37
> Tools • Dart 2.5.0
>
> Flutter doctor: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor
> -v): [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale en-US)
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.1) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0) [✓]
> Android Studio (version 3.4) [✓] VS Code (version 1.38.1) [✓]
> Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!
>
> Xcode Log: unner[32641:729850] save image successful 2019-09-26
> 09:37:58.007237+0300 Runner[32641:729850] [core] "Error returned from
> daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)"" 2019-09-26
> 09:37:58.041160+0300 Runner[32641:729723] Success public.png {
> PHImageFileDataKey = {length = 1715209, bytes = 0x89504e47 0d0a1a0a
> 0000000d 49484452 ... 49454e44 ae426082 }; PHImageFileOrientationKey =
> 0; PHImageFileUTIKey = "public.png"; PHImageResultIsDegradedKey = 0;
> PHImageResultRequestIDKey = 1; } 2019-09-26 09:37:58.041279+0300
> Runner[32641:729723] Success PHImageFileURLKey (null) 2019-09-26
> 09:37:58.044804+0300 Runner[32641:729862]
> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid
> argument(s)
>
> ## 0 _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:263:57)
>
> ## 1 ImagePickerSaver.saveFile (package:image_picker_saver/image_picker_saver.dart:85:34)

Comment: It's working fine after updating the image_picker_saver plugin with the latest version. Thanks for the support. :)

Comment: I am still facing the same error at:
`ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: bytes.buffer.asUint8List())`

I am using **image_picker_saver: 0.3.0**

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine after updating the image_picker_saver plugin with the latest version. Thanks for the support. :) –

Comment: I am still facing the same error at:
`ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: bytes.buffer.asUint8List())`

I am using **image_picker_saver: 0.3.0**